# CStdint использование

Tags: c++

Стоит ли использовать его типы всегда вместо обычных? 
Из плюсов - хорошая переносимость кода, а минусы есть?

Чем значения fast отличаются от не fast?

Чем значения least отличаются от не least?

Когда нужно использовать значения intptr_t/uintptr_t?

А что будет если размер типа не поддерживается платформой ?

Comment: Минусы: не везде он есть. Например в Visual Studio 2008 и более ранних его нет.

Comment: На английском SO есть достаточно развёрнутый ответ на этот вопрос. Если кому-то будет не лень можно сюда продублировать на русском.

Comment: @cybrex: можете хоть ссылку оставить тут?

Comment: [Ссылка.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051) Обычно когда дают ответ со ссылками на английскую версию просят сформулировать ответ здесь и на русском. Я эти типы на практике не использовал поэтому полный ответ пусть лучше кто-нибудь ещё напишет.

Comment: Кто-нибудь...:(

Answer (score 2):

Эти типы (как и заголовочный файл) появились в стандарте C++11.

Переносимость для типов **(u)intX_t** и **(u)intptr_t** не гарантирована.

Если применять их с умом, то минусов нет.

**(u)intX_t** - тип, размер которого строго определён. Не имеет выравнивающих бит и использует [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)) для отрицательных значений. Определён только в архитектурах, поддерживающих его.

**(u)int_fastX_t** - тип, операции над которым будут выполняться быстрее всего на данной архитектуре, и размер которого не ниже указанного.

**(u)int_leastX_t** - тип, размер которого наименьший на данной архитектуре, и размер которого не ниже указанного.

**(u)intptr_t** следует использовать в том случае, когда необходимо поместить значение указателя в целочисленную переменную. Этот тип равен размеру типа указателя.

На сколько мне известно, типы **(u)intX_t**, **(u)int_fastX_t** и **(u)int_leastX_t** одинаковы на архитектуре x86.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint